# MVC 5 blank @html.labelfor

Tags: javascript

just a simple question. i've been trying to make my @html.labelfor a blank label for displaying some computation answers in my web. but it keeps showing "nTotal"(name of the labelfor in my model). can u kindly show me some guides on this? or am i doing it wrong in the first place? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add more details please.

Comment: This question might be silly for an expert, but not for all. Why people are discouraging him with downvote? Anyway, @Dex mateo please add your code snippet if you have done something.

Comment: Please google first and post your code here with your difficulties.

Comment: this is my first time using MVC sir.. i'm sorry for that. this is my code snippet  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.nTotal, new { @id="lblTotal"}). the label is showing the nTotal on the first load of the page.. sorry for being a spoonfeed.. :(

Comment: i've googled the question. it says use displayformat in the model but it won't work for me.. the nTotal is still there..

Comment: more details, some code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Html.LabelFor will display the name (or DispalyFormat) of the respective model property. If you want a blank label use @Html.Label('someid').